# declaring sizes of vectors in a collection. c++

Tags: c++, vector

```
using namespace std;

vector<vector<T> > vec_collection(3);

vec_collection[0]=vector<T>(12);
vec_collection[1]=vector<T>(3);
vec_collection[2]=vector<T>(14);
```

Suppose I have an empty collection of 3 vectors and after initialization, I want the first, second, and third vector to be of specific size 12, 3, and 14 say. Is the above code snippet the right way to declare their sizes?

Comment: "Suppose I have an empty collection of 3 vectors" - actually after 
`vector<vector<T> > vec_collection(3);` you have a collection of 3 empty vectors. `vec_collection` itself isn't empty, its size is of course 3. See also: the difference between an empty box, and a box containing 3 empty boxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code in line of principle creates separated temporary `vector` instances that replace the existing zero-size ones, which in theory means that for every of those lines you have a constructor call (create the temporary), a copy-constructor call (copy it over the existing `vector`) and a destructor call (destroy the temporary).

Although I think that some optimizations could make it actually better than it sounds, it's way easier and almost surely more efficient to simply do:

```
using namespace std;

vector< vector<T> > vec_collection(3);

vec_collection[0].resize(12);
vec_collection[1].resize(3);
vec_collection[2].resize(14);
```

On the other hand, if you need such `vector`s to be always of that fixed size, you should replace them with fixed-size data structures (e.g. a `struct` containing three C-style arrays or `std::array`), as in [@sehe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409081/declaring-sizes-of-vectors-in-a-collection-c/7409111#7409111).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Allthough it doesn't make the vectors fixed-size (vectors can be resized explicitely, or implicitely - e.g. using `push_back` or `insert`).

Finally, vectors can simply be assigned over.

If you need strongtype, fixed-size, jagged nested vectors (urrfff that's a mouth-full):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

using std::array;
using std::tuple;

typedef tuple<
       array<T, 12>,
       array<T, 3>,
       array<T, 14>
    > vec_collection;
```

That would be a bit more awkward to work with, but if speed and container size guarantees were of the essence, go for it.

Note that in pre-TR1 world (say, c++98 with a c++03 library), this would be pretty close to equivalent (but even less comfortable to work with):

```
struct vec_collection
{
     T a[12];
     T b[3];
     T c[14];
};
```

Comment: Strongly typed fixed-size jagged nested vectors - or Sitfisjanvees as we call them in the bizness.

Comment: @Seth: hi name-fellow; I googled that but came up empty... (other Seth)

Comment: Perhaps you would like to use different names for the members of your struct? Or am I missing any subtlety?

Comment: @bitmask: thx for the heads up; typed that up a bit too quickly

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++11, you can do it with an initialiser list, which is more efficient:

```
vector<vector<T>> vec_collection(3) { vector<T>(12), vector<T>(3), vector<T>(14) };
```

Otherwise, you can do it the way you're doing which is fine, or just call `resize` on the elements like in [Matteo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409081/declaring-sizes-of-vectors-in-a-collection-c/7409130#7409130).

Answer (score -1):

```
vector< vector<T>* > vec_collection(3); // i changed it to a vector of vector<T>*


 vec_collection[0]=new vector<MyType>(12);
 //etc
```

You probably want to replace  with  in the code. E.g.

```
vector<int>(12);
```

Moreover, if your vector are fixed size, you can just use arrays.

Comment: Try this and the compiler will give you a long error message stating it cannot convert `vector<T> *` to `vector<T>`

Comment: Ugh no, that's a `vector` of `vector`s, not a `vector` of pointers to `vector`.

Comment: Sorry, my code didn't have 4 leading spaces, and <> wasn't showing :) I fixed it now.

Comment: Yes, you're right about vector<T>*. Let me correct the answer.

Comment: The missing template argument is not the problem, the question shows a vector of vectors, not a vector of pointers to vectors.

Comment: Praetorian - you're absolutely right. I've edited the answer to clarify that. Thanks!

Comment: Well, now your answer is coherent, but no longer refers to this question, since the question is about a `vector< vector<T> >`.

Comment: Ok, this will compile, but what's the benefit? It's just complicated things even more because you must manually delete each element of `vec_collection` before clearing it.

Comment: I suppose I'm second-guessing the original poster a little. It's up to the code owner to decide whether storing pointers or objects in the vector makes more sense in their specific case.

Comment: @Praetorian: I think the idea here is that you do not have to copy the intermediate vector in each assignment. But I do agree that this isn't worth the overhead (still, I find `-2` too harsh, so ...).

Comment: @bitmask Don't look at me, I didn't downvote. I think the downvotes might've been because it wasn't what was asked in the original question.